# Update existing file's content in Google Drive API V3 with uploadType Resumable

Tags: json, upload, google-api, drive

I've been following the [Drive API V3 Resumable Uploads Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#start-resumable) and successfully uploaded new files with Resumable sessions. First a POST request to "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files" with all headers specified correctly (Content-type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" to send metadata as json), then retrieve the Session URI from the Response Header "Location", then PUT request to the Session URI with the contents of the file as the Body.

I am trying to follow the hints the docs gives on updating the data of a current Drive file but this is very confusing. Quoting the Docs:

> If the request succeeds, the server responds with an HTTP 201 Created, along with any metadata associated with this resource. If the initial request of the resumable session had been a PUT, to update an existing resource, the success response would be  200 OK, along with any metadata associated with this resource.

The request I am sending to get the Session URI is:

```
PUT /upload/drive/v3/files/{fileID}?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {authToken}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: {FileToBeSent-Content-Type}
X-Upload-Content-Length: {FileToBeSent-Content-Length}

{ "name" : "myfile.ext"}
```

But the response I get is "Not Found", is there a way to get a Resumable Session URI for an existing file? Am I sending the FileID correctly or should I do it on the second request to the Session URI?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the docs [Migrate to Google drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration):

> All update operations now use PATCH instead of PUT

So this is how a Resumable Upload to an existing file should be done in V3:

First a Patch request to the File URL:

```
PATCH /upload/drive/v3/files/{fileID}?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {authToken}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: {FileToBeSent-Content-Type}
X-Upload-Content-Length: {FileToBeSent-Content-Length}

{ "name" : "myfile.ext"}
```

Then follow the instructions in the docs normally, retrieve the Session URI from the Response and send your file via PUT to it.

Comment: Hi Luis, I am able to get file uploaded to google drive successfully but the metadata information like name and description are missing in the uploaded file.

Step 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM1YeSBEPCuTDNvUENKQjRicVE/view?usp=sharing

Step 1 response: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM1YeSBEPCuZ293ZkVaTzhjdG8/view?usp=sharing

Step 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM1YeSBEPCueDA5YThRQkNCUnM/view?usp=sharing

Step 2 response: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM1YeSBEPCuSzVPUUNtQ3ZhZzQ/view?usp=sharing

Really helpful if you can provide some suggestions.Thanks!